# How do I pass a pointer (that points to a structure) to a function?

Tags: list, function, pointers, struct, linked-list

I want to create a linked list in C, but when I use the code below, gcc throws this error:

> Error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct list')

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct list{
    int age;
    struct list *next;
}; 

void create_item(int *total_items, 
                 struct list where_is_first_item,
                 struct list where_is_last_item)
{

    struct list *generic_item;
    generic_item = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("\nage of item %d: ", (*total_items)+1);
    scanf("%d", &generic_item->age);

    if(*total_items == 0){

        where_is_first_item->next=generic_item;
        where_is_last_item->next=generic_item;
        printf("\nitem created\n");
    }
    else{

        where_is_last_item->next=generic_item;
        printf("\nitem created\n");
    }

int main (void){
    struct list *where_is_first_item;
    struct list *where_is_last_item;
    int total_items=0;
    printf("\n\n\tCREATE A NEW ITEM\n");
    create_item(&total_items, where_is_first_item, where_is_last_item);
    total_items++;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void create_item(int *total_items, struct list *where_is_first_item, struct list *where_is_last_item)
```

Add a star!

You are also referencing invalid memory because you allocate to `generic_item` but then reference `where_is_first_item`. `where_is_first_item` is not allocated to. Try `where_is_first_item = generic_item;` before you use `where_is_first_item`.

You will also find that the pointers in your `main` function remain unmodified because the pointer values are being passed. Here it gets confusing/interesting: if you want your pointers in `main` to be modified you need to pass pointers *to pointers*: `struct_list **where_is_first_item`. Trust me, that is likely to do your head in.

Comment: thank's for your answer. I change the code but when i executed it, it give me 'segmentation fault' after introduce the age of the first item.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass your struct prameters as pointers.

Change:

`create_item(int *total_items, struct list where_is_first_item, struct list where_is_last_item)`

to:

`create_item(int *total_items, struct list *where_is_first_item, struct list *where_is_last_item)`